# Visual Studio How to make a Global Button (System.Windows.Forms.Button button)

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to get a Form button to be global. I tried putting a static in front of public but it gave me a bunch of errors. Any Idea on how to make it global and let other classes change it? Thank you.

Comment: You have some real problem, and you want to solve that real problem with static Button (which is wrong "solution" for any problem). You should ask help with your real problem.

Comment: But please ask help as a new question.

Comment: It can't be static, just *public* is enough.  You make it available to another project just by adding a reference to the assembly.  Or adding it to the toolbox.  Only add it to the toolbox when it is stable and not likely to change anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot (maybe it's possible through a hack, but you should not do it anyway) make it global. You need to pass an instance of your form to the party that wants to change the button. Your form should expose a functionality (method for example) to change that button so that the Button itself does not need to be public either.